# анимация вверх движение css

Tags: html, css, css-animation, animate

Как сделать постоянное движение облаков вверх, как будто они плывут, чтобы не опускались вниз + немного наклон дать, чтобы реалистичнее смотрелось

```css
.sky {
 height: 480px;
 background: #007fd5;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-animation: sky_background 50s ease-out infinite;
 -moz-animation: sky_background 50s ease-out infinite;
 -o-animation: sky_background 50s ease-out infinite;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
}

.moon {
 background: url("http://extremje.beget.tech/assets/img/oblako/moon.png");
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 300%;
 -webkit-animation: moon 50s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: moon 50s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: moon 50s linear infinite;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
}

.clouds_one {
 background: url("http://extremje.beget.tech/assets/img/oblako/cloud_one.png");
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 300%;
 -webkit-animation: cloud_one 50s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: cloud_one 50s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: cloud_one 50s linear infinite;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
}

.clouds_two {
 background: url("http://extremje.beget.tech/assets/img/oblako/cloud_two.png");
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 300%;
 -webkit-animation: cloud_two 75s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: cloud_two 75s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: cloud_two 75s linear infinite;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
}

.clouds_three {
 background: url("http://extremje.beget.tech/assets/img/oblako/cloud_three.png");
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 300%;
 -webkit-animation: cloud_three 100s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: cloud_three 100s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: cloud_three 100s linear infinite;
 -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
}

@-webkit-keyframes sky_background {
 0% {
  background: #007fd5;
  color: #007fd5
 }
 50% {
  background: #007fd5;
  color: #a3d9ff
 }
 100% {
  background: #007fd5;
  color: #007fd5
 }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moon {
   0%{
        transform: translateY(30%);
    }
    50%{
        transform: translateY(-8%);
    }
    65%{
        transform: translateY(4%);
    }
    80%{
        transform: translateY(-4%);
    }
    95%{
        transform: translateY(2%);
    }           
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0%);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cloud_one {
   0%{
        transform: translateY(30%);
    }
    50%{
        transform: translateY(-8%);
    }
    65%{
        transform: translateY(4%);
    }
    80%{
        transform: translateY(-4%);
    }
    95%{
        transform: translateY(2%);
    }           
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0%);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cloud_two {
   0%{
        transform: translateY(30%);
    }
    50%{
        transform: translateY(-8%);
    }
    65%{
        transform: translateY(4%);
    }
    80%{
        transform: translateY(-4%);
    }
    95%{
        transform: translateY(2%);
    }           
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0%);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cloud_three {
   0%{
        transform: translateY(100%);
    }
    50%{
        transform: translateY(-8%);
    }
    65%{
        transform: translateY(4%);
    }
    80%{
        transform: translateY(-4%);
    }
    95%{
        transform: translateY(2%);
    }           
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0%);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes sky_background {
   0%{
        transform: translateY(30%);
    }
    50%{
        transform: translateY(-8%);
    }
    65%{
        transform: translateY(4%);
    }
    80%{
        transform: translateY(-4%);
    }
    95%{
        transform: translateY(2%);
    }           
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0%);
    }
}



@-moz-keyframes cloud_one {
    0%{
        transform: translateY(30%);
    }
    50%{
        transform: translateY(-8%);
    }
    65%{
        transform: translateY(4%);
    }
    80%{
        transform: translateY(-4%);
    }
    95%{
        transform: translateY(2%);
    }           
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0%);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes cloud_two {
   0%{
        transform: translateY(30%);
    }
    50%{
        transform: translateY(-8%);
    }
    65%{
        transform: translateY(4%);
    }
    80%{
        transform: translateY(-4%);
    }
    95%{
        transform: translateY(2%);
    }           
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0%);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes cloud_three {
    0%{
        transform: translateY(30%);
    }
    50%{
        transform: translateY(-8%);
    }
    65%{
        transform: translateY(4%);
    }
    80%{
        transform: translateY(-4%);
    }
    95%{
        transform: translateY(2%);
    }           
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0%);
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700&amp;subset=latin,cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Condensed&amp;subset=latin,cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">


<body class="sky" style="http://extremje.beget.tech/assets/img/golandia/bottom.png">
 <div class="moon"></div>
 <div class="clouds_one"></div>
 <div class="clouds_two"></div>
 <div class="clouds_three"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно через `dispay: none` и возврату в начальное положение

```css
:root {
  --sky_1: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9trI.png');
  --sky_2: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/EI2f5.png');
  --sky_3: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/cN2dg.png');
  --moon: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/WduQ1.png');
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.sky {
  height: 480px;
  background: #007fd5;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.moon {
  background: var(--moon);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  animation: moon 10s linear infinite;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
}

.clouds_one {
  background: var(--sky_1);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  animation: cloud_one 20s linear infinite;
  transform: translate(-100%, 100%);
}

.clouds_two {
  background: var(--sky_2);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  animation: cloud_two 30s linear infinite;
  transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
}

.clouds_three {
  background: var(--sky_3);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200%;
  animation: cloud_three 50s linear infinite;
  transform: translate(-100%, 100%);
}

@keyframes moon {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(20%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-4%);
  }
  65% {
    transform: translateY(4%);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateY(-4%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(20%);
  }
}

@keyframes cloud_one {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 100%);
  }
  96% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    display: none;
    transform: translate(50%, -100%);
  }
  100% {
    display: none;
    transform: translate(-100%, 100%);
  }
}

@keyframes cloud_two {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
  }
  96% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    display: none;
    transform: translate(100%, -100%);
  }
  100% {
    display: none;
    transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cloud_three {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
  }
  96% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    display: none;
    transform: translate(100%, -100%);
  }
  100% {
    display: none;
    transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
  }
}


}
```

```html
<div class="sky">
  <div class="moon"></div>
  <div class="clouds_one"></div>
  <div class="clouds_two"></div>
  <div class="clouds_three"></div>
</div>
```